# Incrementing a variable without interfering with the GUI

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

Am I able to create a parallel loop in Objective-C?
For example, I want to be able to run the normal program, with buttons and other items responding, but also have a continuous loop incrementing an integer every five seconds. Is this possible, or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this.. this will create a timer for 5 seconds in background. Replace your function with your code. that will fire after every 5 seconds

`double delayInSeconds = 5.0; // 5 second delay
 dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
 dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
     //Your code
 });`

Answer (score 0):

1. One solution is running an `NSTimer`. That’s not really a “continuous loop”, but it’s a perfect solution for doing something short each X seconds.
2. Another possibility is writing a regular `for` loop with `sleep` and dispatching it to a background queue (`dispatch_async`, `dispatch_get_global_queue`). That’s a bit more complex than an `NSTimer`, but you also get a real “continuous loop” running in parallel with your regular code.
3. You can also use `-performSelectorInBackground` or create a real background `NSThread` with your loop, but that’s essentially (2), just more complex.

Read the Cocoa [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1) to learn details.